# bootstrap list group onclick not working created through reactjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined why it is not working

https://github.com/ankitsingh101/wp-customizer-api/blob/master/index.html

```
class Sidetabs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.props={
       Data: [
        {
            title:"Globel",
            class:"globe"
        },
       {
           title:"Sections",
           class:"archive"
        },
       {
           title:"Settings",
           class:"cogs"
        },
        {
           title:"Panel",
           class:"columns"
        },
       {
           title:"Control",
           class:"columns"
        },
   ]
}
this.props.Data.map((item, index) => (console.log(item.title)));
}
render() {
  return(
    <div className="list-group">
    {
            this.props.Data.map((item, index) => (
                <a href="#" className="list-group-item text-center" style={{display: item.title==="Panel" ? 'none' : '' }} id={item.title==="Panel"? 'panel-list':''}>
                    <div><h4 className={"fa fa-" + item.class} aria-hidden="true"></h4><br/>{item.title}</div>
                </a>
            ))

    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

}
  ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementsByClassName('bhoechie-tab-menu')[0]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to write stuff to props yourself, `this.props` are the properties the component get sent in from its parent. remove

```
this.props={Data:...}
```

and replace with

```
this.state = {Data:...}
```

then use

```
this.state.Data.map((item, index) => (...)
```